# APPSCRIPT Retrieve Last Interaction Date with an Email Address from Gmail

Tags: google-apps-script

My script is currently "working" but i always get an error with the last row- so its going at 100% failure rate.

I am trying to have app script look in my gmail for the last interaction date for a list of emails that will be constantly changing and more rows will be added.
It shoud loook for both sent or received emails and print the date of that last exchange.

Here is my current script:

```
/**
* @license MIT
* @author xfanatical. 
*/
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var emailsRange = ss.getRangeByName('Emails')
  var getLastMessageDate = ss.getRangeByName('LastReceivedDate')
  
  var emails = emailsRange.getValues()
  for (var i = 1; i <= emails.length; i++) {
    var email = emails[i][0].replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '')
    if (email === '') {
      continue
    }
    var thread = GmailApp.search('to:' + email, 0, 1)
    Logger.log('email = ' + email)
    var targetCell = getLastMessageDate.getCell(i + 1, 1)
    if (thread.length === 0) {
      targetCell.setValue('Not Found')
    } else {
      var messages = thread[0].getMessages()
      for (var j = messages.length - 1; j >= 0; j -= 1) {
        var message = messages[j]
        Logger.log('checking message: ' + message.getTo())
        if (message.getTo().indexOf(email) !== -1) {
          var date = message.getDate()
          var dateStr = date.getDate() + "/"
                + (date.getMonth()+1)  + "/" 
                + date.getFullYear()  
          targetCell.setValue(dateStr)
          break
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am getting the following error:

Error   TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
at myFunction(Code:12:26)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to remove the error of `Error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0') at myFunction(Code:12:26)`.

When I saw your script, I thought that `for (var i = 1; i <= emails.length; i++) {` is the reason for your current issue. When the loop is run with this condition, when `i` is `emails.length`, an error occurs at `emails[i][0]` because `emails[i]` is undefined. So, in this case, as a simple modification, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= emails.length; i++) {
```

#### To:

```
for (var i = 1; i < emails.length; i++) {
```

#### Note:

- I think that as another approach, `forEach`, `map` can be also used. But, from your showing script, I thought that the above modification might help understand the reason for your current issue. So, I proposed it.

Comment: Thank you! Very much appreciated it. Scratched my head over this for hours.

Comment: @Jorge Fernando García Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.